# omnetpp "imported NED type not found"

Tags: importerror, omnet++

I'm very new to Omnet++. I'm trying to simulate a very basic network but I'm having problems with importing a StandardHost.

This is the source of my NED file:

```
package lucas.simulations;

import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;

network Network
{

}
```

Now, the line `import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;` gives me the following error on the IDE: `imported NED type not found`. However, if I do go into the installation folder, I get to see the `StandardHost.ned` file:

```
lucas@test:~/omnetpp-5.2.1/samples/inet/src/inet/node/inet$ ls 
drwxrwxr-x  2 lucas lucas 4096 feb 19 18:20 ./
drwxrwxr-x 18 lucas lucas 4096 feb 19 18:20 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 lucas lucas 1570 feb 19 18:20 AdhocHost.ned
-rw-rw-r--  1 lucas lucas 8765 feb 19 18:20 ChangeLog
-rw-rw-r--  1 lucas lucas 1107 feb 19 18:20 INetworkNode.ned
-rw-rw-r--  1 lucas lucas  861 feb 19 18:20 MulticastRouter.ned
-rw-rw-r--  1 lucas lucas 7030 feb 19 18:20 NodeBase.ned
-rw-rw-r--  1 lucas lucas 4755 feb 19 18:20 Router.ned
-rw-rw-r--  1 lucas lucas 5537 feb 19 18:20 StandardHost.ned
-rw-rw-r--  1 lucas lucas 1188 feb 19 18:20 WirelessHost.ned
```

Moreover, according to [this](https://inet.omnetpp.org/inet-tutorials/showfile.html?url=configurator/ConfiguratorA.ned), that should be the appropriate way of declaring it.

So, which is the proper way of declaring the `import` in the main NED file?

Thanks!

Lucas

Comment: Have you marked `inet` as referenced project in properties of your project?

Comment: Thank you very much: that did it! Cheers!